# How to Compare SOQL Query Results

Tags: apex, soql

**For Example:**

```
 for(Contact con : [Select Id,Salary__c From Contact Where AccountId = :accId Limit 100]){
            System.debug('Check min'+con.Salary__c);
 }
```

How to loop though the results and retrieve the minimum salary without changing my SOQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just looking to compare it on the loop, you can use this:

```java
Contact minSalCon;
Decimal minSal;
for(Contact con : [Select Id,Salary__c From Contact Where AccountId = :accId Limit 100]){
    System.debug('Check min'+con.Salary__c);
    if(minSal == null || con.Salary__c < minSal){
        minSal = con.Salary__c;
        minSalCon = con; //in case you need to do some logic on the contact
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx! That is what I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query:

```
for(AggregateResult agr : [Select AccountId accId, MIN(Salary__c) minSal From                
                           Contact Where AccountId =: accId Limit 100 group by AccountId]){
      System.debug('Check min'+agr .get('minSal'));
 }
```

You can use this query for multiple Accounts as well

Comment: I want custom functionality for ex using for loop, I already Used AggregateResult and its working fine.

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause does not work well in aggregate queries.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what the query actually does (ie. uses an Aggregate Function).

Comment: @avidForce Can you explain why you're not looking for a query that uses Aggregate Functions? Using `MIN()` is about as efficient as it gets. If you have something that's already working, why are you looking to rewrite it using code that is more complex?

Comment: @Darek F Just want to create and see my own logic, I know using AggregateResult is more efficient.